# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (None, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I finish trained my model that consist of 20 classes and reach 0.9993 accuracy and currently working for testing. I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4K6D_gx2Iw&t=2s) but im getting error at

```
prediction = model.predict(['test1.jpg'])
```

The training data is defined as

```
for features, label in training_data:
    x.append(features)
    y.append(label)

x = np.array(x).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE,1)
```

and this is my definition for cnn

```
x = pickle.load(open("x.pickle", "rb" ))
y = pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb"))

x = x/255.0

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), input_shape = x.shape[1:IMG_SIZE]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), input_shape  = x.shape[1:IMG_SIZE]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(20))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
```

here also my summary for my model

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 222, 222, 64)      640       
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 222, 222, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 111, 111, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 109, 109, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 109, 109, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 54, 54, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 186624)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 64)                11944000  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 20)                1300      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 20)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 11,982,868
Trainable params: 11,982,868
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The error that I get is

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 prediction = model.predict(['test1.jpg'])
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks,
>   max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
>       907         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
>       908         workers=workers,
>   --> 909         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
>       910 
>       911   def reset_metrics(self):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py
>   in predict(self, model, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks,
>   **kwargs)
>       460     return self._model_iteration(
>       461         model, ModeKeys.PREDICT, x=x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose,
>   --> 462         steps=steps, callbacks=callbacks, **kwargs)
>       463 
>       464
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py
>   in _model_iteration(self, model, mode, x, y, batch_size, verbose,
>   sample_weight, steps, callbacks, **kwargs)
>       442               mode=mode,
>       443               training_context=training_context,
>   --> 444               total_epochs=1)
>       445           cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, result, mode)
>       446
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py
>   in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size,
>   batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode,
>   training_context, total_epochs)
>       121         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
>       122       try:
>   --> 123         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
>       124       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
>       125         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py
>   in execution_function(input_fn)
>        84     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
>        85     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
>   ---> 86                               distributed_function(input_fn))
>        87 
>        88   return execution_function
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwds)
>       455 
>       456     tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
>   --> 457     result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
>       458     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
>       459       self._call_counter.called_without_tracing()
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py
>   in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
>       501       # This is the first call of **call**, so we have to initialize.
>       502       initializer_map = object_identity.ObjectIdentityDictionary()
>   --> 503       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializer_map)
>       504     finally:
>       505       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py
>   in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
>       406     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
>       407         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(
>
> ## pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> --> 408             *args, **kwds))
>       409 
>       410     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py
>   in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args,
>   **kwargs)    1846     if self.input_signature:    1847       args, kwargs = None, None
>   -> 1848     graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)    1849     return graph_function    1850
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py
>   in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)    2148
>   graph_function = self._function_cache.primary.get(cache_key, None)
>   2149         if graph_function is None:
>   -> 2150           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)    2151           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] =
>   graph_function    2152         return graph_function, args, kwargs
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py
>   in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs,
>   override_flat_arg_shapes)    2039             arg_names=arg_names,
>   2040             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
>   -> 2041             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),    2042         self._function_attributes,    2043         # Tell the ConcreteFunction
>   to clean up its graph once it goes out of
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py
>   in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature,
>   func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies,
>   arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value,
>   override_flat_arg_shapes)
>       913                                           converted_func)
>       914 
>   --> 915       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
>       916 
>       917       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py
>   in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
>       356         # **wrapped** allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
>       357         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
>   --> 358         return weak_wrapped_fn().**wrapped**(*args, **kwds)
>       359     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
>       360
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py
>   in distributed_function(input_iterator)
>        71     strategy = distribution_strategy_context.get_strategy()
>        72     outputs = strategy.experimental_run_v2(
>   ---> 73         per_replica_function, args=(model, x, y, sample_weights))
>        74     # Out of PerReplica outputs reduce or pick values to return.
>        75     all_outputs = dist_utils.unwrap_output_dict(
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py
>   in experimental_run_v2(self, fn, args, kwargs)
>       758       fn = autograph.tf_convert(fn, ag_ctx.control_status_ctx(),
>       759                                 convert_by_default=False)
>   --> 760       return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
>       761 
>       762   def reduce(self, reduce_op, value, axis):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py
>   in call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)    1785       kwargs
>   = {}    1786     with self._container_strategy().scope():
>   -> 1787       return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)    1788     1789   def _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py
>   in _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)    2130
>   self._container_strategy(),    2131
>   replica_id_in_sync_group=constant_op.constant(0, dtypes.int32)):
>   -> 2132       return fn(*args, **kwargs)    2133     2134   def _reduce_to(self, reduce_op, value, destinations):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\autograph\impl\api.py
>   in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
>       290   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
>       291     with ag_ctx.ControlStatusCtx(status=ag_ctx.Status.DISABLED):
>   --> 292       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       293 
>       294   if inspect.isfunction(func) or inspect.ismethod(func):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py
>   in _predict_on_batch(***failed resolving arguments***)
>       160     def _predict_on_batch(model, x, y=None, sample_weights=None):
>       161       del y, sample_weights
>   --> 162       return predict_on_batch(model, x)
>       163 
>       164     func = _predict_on_batch
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py
>   in predict_on_batch(model, x)
>       357   # Validate and standardize user data.
>       358   inputs, _, _ = model._standardize_user_data(
>   --> 359       x, extract_tensors_from_dataset=True)
>       360 
>       361   # If `model._distribution_strategy` is True, then we are in a replica context
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight,
>   batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle,
>   extract_tensors_from_dataset)    2470           feed_input_shapes,
>   2471           check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch
>   size.
>   -> 2472           exception_prefix='input')    2473     2474     # Get typespecs for the input data and sanitize it if necessary.
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py
>   in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis,
>   exception_prefix)
>
> ```
>  563                            ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
>  564                            str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
> ```
>
> --> 565                            'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
>        566         if not check_batch_axis:
>        567           data_shape = data_shape[1:]
>
> **ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (None, 1)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your input_shape for the first `conv` layer seems wrong.

`input_shape = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE,1)`

`model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), input_shape = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE,1))`

Secondly, no need to specify `input_shape` for any intermediate layers.

`model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), input_shape  = x.shape[1:IMG_SIZE]))` should be

`model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3))`

Comment: I changed as you suggest but still getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to predict on some string `['test1.jpg']`, why? You need to prepare the data to be the same shape and distribution as used for training - for example - load the image, resize/crop it to the relevant size, normalize it to be in range `[0,1]` (if this is what you did during training) etc...

Comment: yes i just realized that i did'n prepare the data like you said, thank you for see that for me!